# Contradiction regarding friction of a rolling cylinder in an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I came upon this while wondering whether the friction of a rolling cylinder on an inclined plane depends on the value of friction coefficient.

[image]

now,
$$f\leqq\upsilon N$$

Again after calculating I found that the
$$f=\frac{mg\sin\theta}{3}$$
So,$$\frac{mg\sin\theta}{3}\leqq \upsilon mg\cos\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan\theta\leqq 3\upsilon$$
But, I can set the angle and mu to be such that this relation does not hold!

What will happen then? Please explain.

Comment: I cannot think of an appropriate title.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the condition is violated (because $\theta$ is too big) the contact point of the cylinder with the plane has not vanishing velocity and so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is an example of rolling without slipping. A very good explanation of this concept is given [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64555/what-do-people-actually-mean-by-rolling-without-slipping). In this case, it implies that rolling without slipping occurs if $\tan \theta \leq 3 \mu$. The expression validates one's intuition too. Its easy to observe that a cylinder tends to roll without slipping when kept on a wedge with lesser slope.

Comment: But i have never assumed while finding f that it is rolling without slipping!i cannot understand what you are trying to tell.

Comment: You did when using the equivalence between angular speed and linear speed.