# Does rolling without slipping or pure rolling mean friction is not acting?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction

Does rolling without slipping imply pure rolling? Also please explain what is slipping, skidding, rolling involving and not involving slipping and when to take max or min friction?

Comment: Potential answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64555

Answer (score 1):

For wheel, rod, ball etc..:

*Rolling without slipping* means rolling **and** moving forward as characterized by **a=$\alpha$*r** where a is the linear acceleration of center of mass and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration around center of mass. The object and surface do not "rub" against each other and no energy is lost to heat. This is a case where static friction is applied. Static friction may be high or low, but limited to a maximum. The static friction is causing or aiding the roll movement.

*Skidding* is a situation where **a>$\alpha$*r**. In its extreme, the objects slides without any rotation. In this case, dynamic friction is operating and energy is lost to heat. Dynamic friction is again aiding the roll but is opposing the linear acceleration.